# Placing arbitrary braces as statements - what do they mean?

Tags: java

The following is a valid Java program:

```
public class _ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            {
                {
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Do those curly braces add extra semantics? Or are they treated just like whitespace?

Comment: Nice class name ;-): `_ _o_ = new _();`

Comment: Not sure about Java but between Haskell, Python, ..., programmers using an underscore has the implicit meaning 'doesn't matter'. In Ruby it even has some actual semantics to the compiler: http://po-ru.com/diary/rubys-magic-underscore/

Comment: @assylias. Why `_o_` as reference name? Just `_` would do ->  `_ _ = new _();` lol

Comment: None of the answers have mentioned that you should almost always create a new method instead of creating this kind of local scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The curly braces just create a local block scope inside your main method. The variables declared inside a block will not be visible outside.

This way of coding is used to minimize the scope of local variables.

```
public void someMethod() {
    {
        int x = 10;
        System.out.println(x); // Ok
    }
    System.out.println(x); // Error, x not visible here
}
```

It is a good practice to minimize the scope of the local variables you create, specially when you know they won't be used anywhere else in your program. So, it doesn't make sense to let it in the larger scope till it ends. Just create a local block scope, so that it will be eligible for `Garbage Collection` as soon as the block ends.

Also see [`@Bohemian's`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145551/1679863) answer below that also quotes one more benefit.

Comment: As far as GC is concerned, the object is eligible for it immediately after the last use of the local var. HotSpot uses this routinely.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik. So can the actual reason be to not let that variable be used at place where it is not intended to use? Can you post some good reason.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it helps to reuse the same var name, for example in GUI-building code that uses a lot of same-typed objects (like `GridBagConstraints`). And, as @bohemian notes below, they are great for copy-pasting code :)

Answer (score 4):

They are a code block. They can be handy when copy-pasting code that contains local variable declarations:

```
{
    int x = foo * bar;
    someMethod(x);
}
{
    int x = foo * y; // won't get "already defined variable" compile error
    someMethod(x);
}
```

I've also seen them used for code generation, so you can safely add some code to a method and define a variable without having to worry if it's been defined earlier in the method.

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces are meant to define and limit scope. Since they do not enclose any statements or declarations, they would eliminated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The only purpose of the extra braces is to provide scope-limit. The variable a

```
void ad()
    {
    int a;
    }
```

will only exist within those braces, and will have no scope outside of them.